# Computing the probability of a type-1 error

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_{130}$ be a sample from $GAM(θ, k).$ This sample is used for a
hypothesis test. The null hypothesis is
$θ = 2$ and $k = 2$
and the alternative hypothesis is irrelevant for this question. The test statistic is
$\log(X_{0.3}),$
where log is the natural logarithm and $X_{0.3}$ is the 30th percentile of the sample. The
critical region for this hypothesis test and this test statistic is
(−∞, 0.477] .
Compute (approximately) α, the probability of a type-I error.

Comment: I find this to be an interesting problem. I wish you had shown some of your thoughts or work towards a solution because I am not sure exactly why you are asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

This question is clearly copyrighted by the University of Amsterdam teacher as this is one of the assignment questions which is only due on 6/11/2020. Don't cheat.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible parameterizations of a gamma distribution: one in which the second parameter is a scale parameter and on in which the second parameter is a rate parameter. In your case it makes a difference whether
the mean of the distribution is 4 or 1, respectively. I have interpreted $k$ as a scale parameter, so that the rate (used by R) is $1/k.$

[Also, the rejection region is clearly for a one-sided test, so it is not quite accurate to say that the alternative is irrelevant, even though we do not have *particular* alternative values of
the parameters in mind.]

For an analytic solution you'd need to derive the distribution of the 39th order statistic $X_{39:130}$ in a sample of size 130 (see Note). Then find the probability in that distribution below $\ln(X_{39:130}).$

Below I have given an approximate solution by simulating (in R)
a million samples of size 120. It seems $\alpha \approx 0.0015.$

```
set.seed(2020)
n = 130;  k = 2
x.3 = replicate(10^6, quantile(rgamma(n,k,1/k),.3))
mean(log(x.3) <= 0.477)
[1] 0.001453
```

[image]

```
hist(x.3, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2")
 abline(v = exp(.477), col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

*Note:* The simulated distribution of $X_{36:120}$ seems
approximately normal, so you might be able to use the
asymptotic normal distribution of the 30th quantile.